# Strange crashes on the iPad device with core graphics functions

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad, core-graphics, cgimage

I am getting a lot of strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes on the iPad that only happen on the device and not in the simulator. I am assuming that they are somehow memory related, but I am not sure. They all happen with image context related functions.

One strange example is using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect. For example, if i run through a bunch of UIImages and crop them with CGImageCreateWithImageInRect, it will always crash at specific arbitrary sizes. Like, if I crop them all to 200x200, it crashes out after processing 12 images. If i crop them to 210x210, it works no problem.

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens inside of "memmove" called from "CGBlt_copyBytes". That is all the debugger shows me strangely enough. I can't see the callstack going up to any of my methods.

All of this works fine in the simulator!

I know this is all very vague, but if anyone has any ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit question and add code so we can analyze.

Answer (score 0):

Start by doing things like checking for zombies, and running clang (Build & Analyze) to see if you have memory management issues. I think you'll need to post more code, because this does sound like memory stomping.